# What package is responsible for the "Recents" button to work?

Tags: adb, system-apps, recents-screen

### Background:

I wanted to customize my phone a little bit, a Samsung Galaxy A70 (SM-A705FN), and that process included de-bloating it. I opened xda-developers, looked around, and finally found a [list of bloatware to remove](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pNtEklDbOadzdO67mWgm6hlKm9GIA4MzKd_EHUQGcIg/edit?usp=sharing).
I threw in a few other packages that I checked, such as Samsung Radio, Google Duo, Netflix, and a few other things that I am 100% certain didn't have anything to do with my issue.

I then opened an ADB Connection and through the shell I uninstalled the packages, one by one, using this command:

```
pm uninstall --user 0 com.facebook.katana
```

Obviously I swapped around the package names for each package.
I tried to remove everything, somethings weren't removed, overall everything's great!

### The issue:

Just now, several hours later, I noticed that my "Recents" button in the navigation bar is not doing anything. The effect is there, so I believe it registers the press, but I think I removed whatever handles that request. From what I gathered, it should be easy enough to re-install the package once I find what its called, but I've been looking for a while, and my only other option right now (except for factory resetting and just, like, living with it) is to manually check each permission in that list, which is going to be tedious.

### Bottom line:

Does anyone know what package is responsible for handling the "Recents" button request? or of a better / easier way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Found it after scanning through the list, turns out One UI is responsible for it. For anyone looking in the future, it's `com.sec.android.app.launcher`.